# Java Quartz/Cron Mongodb Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, mongodb, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am planning to have a large collection containing items that need to be processed by a Quartz/cron job. So the cron job will set to run periodically and access mongodb to find the 5 oldest items and process them.

This would be ok for a single server running the cron job. But, later on if i run 2 servers each running the same cron job, I fear that the 2 cron jobs may run at same time and grab 5 same items which may lead to race condition issues.

What is the best practice to avoid this problem?

I'm thinking of putting logic to each job to grab the 5 oldest items that have PENDING status, then immediately change the status to PROCESSED so that other jobs cannot process them. Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I got using quartz scheduler.
You have to involved data base. I am sharing the GitHub link so you can follow the given code.

https://github.com/faizakram/Spring_MongoDb_Quartz_Cluster

Any confusions please comment so I can improve my way to understand

Thanks

Comment: the github lacks some documentation, would you mind explain how this would solve the issue in layman's term?

Comment: I got the documentation from quartz site. You can also find from there.